# Listen for broadcast in sub directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to AngularJS and need some help.  I have two directives (parent and child).  When I click a link, the parent directive will fire a broadcast event that the child directive is listening for.  Mainly I can't get the broadcast listener to capture the broadcasted event when it is fired.  Here is my code so far:

```
<div all-checkboxes-broadcast>
   <a href="" ng-click="checkAll()">Select All</a>
   <a href="" ng-click="clearAll()">Clear All</a>
   <div all-checkboxes-listeners>
      <input type="checkbox" />
   </div>
</div>
```

AllCheckboxesBroadcast.js

```
"use strict";

app.directive('allCheckboxesBroadcast', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: ['$scope',
            function($scope) {
                //select all checkboxes
                $scope.checkAll = function () {
                    $scope.$broadcast('allCheckboxes',true);
                };

                //de-select all checkboxes
                $scope.clearAll = function () {
                    $scope.$broadcast('allCheckboxes',false);
                };
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

AllCheckboxesListener.js

```
"use strict";

app.directive('allCheckboxesListener', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^allCheckboxesBroadcast',
        link: function() {
            if ($scope.$on('allCheckboxes') == true) {
                angular.forEach(element.find('input[type=checkbox]'), function(){ 
                    this.prop('checked',true);
                }); 
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: is your `link: function() {` really `link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {`??

Comment: Yes, it should have had the $scope, $element, $attrs as parameters.

Comment: Instead of using $broadcast, bind to a model (an array of Booleans, or array of items with a Boolean property). The angular way vs jquery way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so a few things... The directive name must match camel cased version i.e. "allCheckboxesListeners" in your case. You have one with an "s" on the end and one without. Regarding the scope, any directive within another will automatically get the same scope unless you start specifying otherwise. So just add it as a parameter in your `link` function and it'll be the parent scope which is available. Also I would not use `find()` when using angular. Instead I would bind those checkboxes to some array of objects so you don't have to manipulate the DOM! Also unless you're using the full version of jQuery alongside, you are limited to searching by tag names in jqLite, which is what angular uses unless you have jQuery added separately (e.g. you'd be limited to searching by only `input` for example).

See example in action here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/0n1NVpAl2u8PYyPd6ygL?p=preview

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('appExample', [])
.directive('allCheckboxesBroadcast', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.checkAll = function () {
            console.log('checkAll');
            $scope.$broadcast('allCheckboxes', true);
        }
        //de-select all checkboxes
        $scope.clearAll = function () {
            console.log('clearAll');
            $scope.$broadcast('allCheckboxes', false);
        };
    }
};
})  
.directive('allCheckboxesListeners', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on('allCheckboxes', function(event, shouldCheckAllCheckboxes) {
                console.log(shouldCheckAllCheckboxes);
                element.find('input').prop('checked', shouldCheckAllCheckboxes);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="appExample">
  <div all-checkboxes-broadcast>
    <a href="" ng-click="checkAll()">Select All</a>
    <a href="" ng-click="clearAll()">Clear All</a>

    <div all-checkboxes-listeners>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please explain "Instead I would bind those checkboxes to some array of objects".  What are the risks when manipulating the DOM?

Comment: Sure! With angular you usually update a variable or object that your checkbox(s) are bound to, and angular will do the checking/unchecking for you. This means the state of your objects is the truth, not the page. So in your case you could have multiple checkboxes bound to multiple objects which are declared on your scope (or an array of objects). When you do your broadcast, you should only have to change your objects. I can update your example later when I get some time if that helps you, otherwise have a google around for ng-checked and checkboxes with ng-repeat.