# Directive to directive scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

This is related to a question: [Listen for broadcast in sub directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642521/listen-for-broadcast-in-sub-directive)

I have two directives, one is a child, one is a parent.  The issue is, I what the child to only catch an event of the parent directive.  Here is what I need:

I have some check boxes and a select all button for a group of check boxes.  When I click the "select all" button, I want it to select all the boxes.  This part I have working.  The catch is I have two instances of this on the page.  Right now when I click "select all", all of the check boxes on the page are selected, not just the ones inside the directive instance.  I'm sure this is a scope problem... but I'm not sure what. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div all-checkboxes-broadcast>
  <div all-checkboxes-listener>
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
  <a ng-click="checkAll()" href="">Select All</a> <!-- this should ONLY check the boxes above, not the ones below.  Currently clicking either select checks all the boxes on the page.-->
</div>

<div all-checkboxes-broadcast>
  <div all-checkboxes-listener>
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
  <a ng-click="checkAll()" href="">Select All</a>
</div>
```

AngularJS:

```
app.directive('allCheckboxesBroadcast', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        controller: ["$scope",function($scope) {
            //select all checkboxes
            $scope.checkAll = function () {
                $scope.$broadcast('allCheckboxes',true);
            };
        }]
    }
}]);

app.directive('allCheckboxesListener', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^allCheckboxesBroadcast',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on('allCheckboxes', function(event, shouldCheckAll) {
                element.find('input').prop('checked',shouldCheckAll);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Edit: I found the answer myself.  By adding "scope: true" to the parent directive, it creates a child scope that will prototypically inherit from its parent, which creates the functionality I was looking for.  If anyone has a better way to do it, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself. By adding "scope: true" to the parent directive (I changed my original question to include this edit), it creates a child scope that will prototypically inherit from its parent, which creates the functionality I was looking for. If anyone has a better way to do it, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to isolate the scope by adding a parameter in your return object in the `allCheckboxesBroadcast` directive, eg: `scope: {}`

Something you might wanna do also is label those directives:

```
<div all-checkboxes-broadcast="1">
  <div all-checkboxes-listener="1">
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
  <a ng-click="checkAll()" href="">Select All</a> <!-- this should ONLY check the boxes above, not the ones below.  Currently clicking either select checks all the boxes on the page.-->
</div>


<div all-checkboxes-broadcast="2">
  <div all-checkboxes-listener="2">
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
  <a ng-click="checkAll()" href="">Select All</a>
</div>
```

Then:

```
app.directive('allCheckboxesBroadcast', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { bcId: "&allCheckboxesBroadcast" },
        controller: ["$scope",function($scope) {
            //select all checkboxes
            $scope.checkAll = function () {
                $scope.$broadcast('allCheckboxes',true, $scope.bcId);
            };
        }]
    }
}]);

app.directive('allCheckboxesListener', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { bcId: "&allCheckboxesListener" },
        require: '^allCheckboxesBroadcast',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on('allCheckboxes', function(event, shouldCheckAll, id) {
              if(id == scope.bcId){
                element.find('input').prop('checked',shouldCheckAll);
              }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

This is a workaround I am using in one of my modules. If you find better options, let me know.

Update: I fixed your plnkr, took me longer than I thought, I am no angular expert and isolated scopes can mess with my mind still. The main issue was that you didn't use a template so your methods defined in your directives were not accessible in the html. I also replaced the `&` by `=` in the scope assignment. I thought `&` would work but I guess I should read the doc again. Anyway, there it is:

http://plnkr.co/edit/J2qBBj3R0rEkfxgPBE84?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the response Alex.  I see what you did but this didn't work for me (I'm not sure why yet).  I'll put together an example later today to make this easier to explain.

Comment: Here is the [working example of your code in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yjVjmxtsVfbOhqmnOHTD), Alex.  Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Let me know if my solution works for you.

Comment: @timg19 yeah, I went in the opposite direction, mainly because I was pushing for indexing your directives. You might wanna keep my answer in mind because it contains other interesting facts about scopes :). I found an actual explanation of directive scopes here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/7Rnd5RjdlCc

Comment: Alex, your solution is definitely worth using if you need to access a specific directive instance.  The link you sent was actually where I found my answer, so we were on the same page.  Thanks again.